# 00001 root /sbin/launchd

Tags: osx, ps

When check the pstree

```
$ pstree -g 2 -p $$ | sed "s/$USER/me/g"
─┬◆ 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 └─┬◆ 00277 me /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_40970
   └─┬◆ 00360 root login -pfl me /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /usr/local/bin/bash
     └─┬◆ 00368 me -bash
       ├─┬◆ 03968 me pstree -g 2 -p 368
       │ └─── 03970 root ps -axwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
       └─── 03969 me sed s/me/me/g
```

I found that `root /sbin/launchd` is No.0001 process, does it mean `/sbin/launchd` run immediately after power on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. PID 1 runs immediately after boot and cannot exit. If it exits, it will trigger a kernel panic.